# HTMLReader having difficulty scraping video links

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, swift

I am using [HTMLReader](https://github.com/nolanw/HTMLReader) to scrap video links in an app. However, there seems to be no options to scrap by video ids and the most common usage are usually for images instead.

**Problem with selectors**

I want to get the src of this video id. I can get the preceding div before the video id but I am unable to ge the exact video id whereby I would get the src next.

```
let someHTML = document.nodesMatchingSelector(".my_video_1_html5_api")
```

My attempt was to refer directly to the video id

```
<video id="my_video_1_html5_api"     class="vjs-tech" preload="auto" src="https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&amp;id=45d2fdf73f5ea442&amp;itag=22&amp;source=picasa&amp;cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&amp;ip=0.0.0.0&amp;ipbits=0&amp;expire=1438962730&amp;sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&amp;signature=A1870313E674D7D0FAAA420CB49BAC57C744A158.45144C1E44617AE5405CE7A27517A4B84DDAE50C&amp;key=lh1"></video>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access to the `attributes` of the nodes using :

```
let someHTML = document.nodesMatchingSelector(".vjs-tech")

for node in someHTML {
    print(node.attributes["src"]!)
}
```

You can use the [CSS-Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) by class or by attribute, take a look in the following sample:

- `let someHTML = document.nodesMatchingSelector(".vjs-tech")` **Represents an element whose class is `vjs-tech`**
- `let someHTML = document.nodesMatchingSelector("[video id]")` **Represents an element with the `video id` attribute, whatever the value of the attribute.**

I hope this help you.

Comment: someHTML prints as nil so it isn't able to retrieve any src

Comment: See updated answer , you need to match with a correct Css selector.

Comment: It is weird, someHTML still prints out as nil when I tried those suggestions. I tried retrieving some other random divs which is not a video id and it worked fine

Comment: Do you testing using the class name?

Comment: Yes I tried using the video id, class name and also copying the CSS path but none of them worked.  this div is nested under a div preload, could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes it could be loaded by AJAX , not loaded initially and then not included in the DOM.

Comment: @VictorSigler Your link to the CSS-Selectors documentation saved my day . Particularly this was the syntax I was looking for `E[foo*="bar"]` : an E element whose "foo" attribute value contains the substring "bar". Note the difference with `E[foo="bar"]` where the "foo" attribute is exactly equal to "bar".